# Sum alternating n rows in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum, rows

I have a trouble trying to solve the following. I would like to add every n columns keeping the number of columns. In detail:

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(32).reshape((8, 4)))`

```
        0   1   2   3
    0   0   1   2   3
    1   4   5   6   7
    2   8   9  10  11
    3  12  13  14  15
    4  16  17  18  19
    5  20  21  22  23
    6  24  25  26  27
    7  28  29  30  31
```

When adding  every 2 rows, i.e., indexes (0, 2, 4, 6) and (1, 3, 5, 7). The result should be:

```
    0   1   2
0  48  52  56
1  64  68  72
```

Of course, this a simple DataFrame, but I have to add every 1000 rows in a 50000x5000 matrix. In that case, I would add rows (0, 1000, 2000, ...), (1, 1001, 2001, ...), etc. The result should be a 50x5000 DataFrame.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `groupby` `index` with `%` `2`

```
df.groupby(df.index%2).sum()# you may change the df.index to np.arange(len(df))
    0   1   2   3
0  48  52  56  60
1  64  68  72  76
```